# How to set js value into jsp variable after click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Here I want set js value (table name) which is in javascript, want to set this js value in jsp variable after click button

what would be my Javascript and JSP?

```
<div id="header"> 
<h3></h3>
<form action="ResultsetMetaDataEx.jsp" method="post" name="">
    <button id="marksheet" value="marksheet" class="marksheet" onclick="call(); ">marksheet</button>
    <button name="btn" id="company" value="company" class="company">company</button>
    <button name="btn" id="book" value="book" class="book">book</button>
</form>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  
$('.marksheet').click(function(){  
  call(){
   var tablename = this.id;
   alert(tablename);
   window.location.replace("ResultsetMetaDataEx.jsp?tablename="+tablename); 
  }
 });
 
</script>
```

Comment: Send it through a form would do?

Comment: Check this url. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116058/how-can-i-access-javascript-variables-in-jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116058/how-can-i-access-javascript-variables-in-jsp)

Comment: i want get value from that button which i clicked nd that value i want to use in jsp