# set html attribute value using JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

In my JSP page I have below checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" <%=checkBoxStatus> ></input>
```

How to replace <%=checkBoxStatus> in above code with JSTL?

Comment: `checkBoxStatus` is javascript variable and you want to use it in JSTL ? is this what you are asking?

Comment: ${object.checkBoxStatus} ${checkBoxStatus} ? I'm not exactly sure what you're after though as @Srinu said.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i access javascript variables in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116058/how-can-i-access-javascript-variables-in-jsp)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" value="${checkBoxStatus}">
```